# Raspberry Pi 3 with ArchARM and encrypted disk will not boot: How can be identified at what stage it fails?

Tags: boot-issues, archlinux, setup

I realize that it is always a bit tricky to configure devices with root disk encryption. So I was not overly surprised that this one does not boot.

However, I am having difficulty saying what exactly is wrong.

**What it should do**

I followed largely [this howto](https://gist.github.com/pezz/5310082) (though not entirely since it is several years old, is for Raspberry Pi 1, not 3, and uses `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `/boot/config.txt`, not `/boot/boot.txt`.

- It should use the configuration from `/boot/boot.txt` (or, rather `/boot/boot.scr`), which is

  ```
  # After modifying, run ./mkscr

  # Set root partition to the second partition of boot device
  #part uuid ${devtype} ${devnum}:2 uuid

  setenv bootargs console=ttyGS0,115200 console=${console} ip=192.168.0.10::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:pi:eth0:none cryptdevice=/dev/mmcblk0p3:root root=/dev/mapper/root rw rootwait loglevel=5

  if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${kernel_addr_r} /Image; then
    if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${fdt_addr_r} /dtbs/${fdtfile}; then
      if load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${ramdisk_addr_r} /initramfs-linux.img; then
        booti ${kernel_addr_r} ${ramdisk_addr_r}:${filesize} ${fdt_addr_r};
      else
        booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r};
      fi;
    fi;
  fi
  ```
- It should boot the kernel `/boot/Image`
- It should use initrd `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` which is generated by the following `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`

  ```
  # vim:set ft=sh
  # MODULES
  # The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
  # run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
  # in this array.  For instance:
  #     MODULES="piix ide_disk reiserfs"
  MODULES=""

  # BINARIES
  # This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
  # wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
  # override the actual binaries included by a given hook
  # BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
  BINARIES=""

  # FILES
  # This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
  # as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
  FILES=""

  # HOOKS
  # This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
  # modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
  # Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
  # order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
  # help on a given hook.
  # 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
  # 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
  # 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
  # Examples:
  ##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
  ##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
  #    HOOKS="base"
  #
  ##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
  ##   work as a sane default
  #    HOOKS="base udev autodetect block filesystems"
  #
  ##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
  ##   No autodetection is done.
  #    HOOKS="base udev block filesystems"
  #
  ##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
  ##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
  #    HOOKS="base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems"
  #
  ##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
  #    HOOKS="base udev block lvm2 filesystems"
  #
  ##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
  #    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
  HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard dropbear encryptssh filesystems fsck"

  # COMPRESSION
  # Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
  # is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
  #COMPRESSION="gzip"
  #COMPRESSION="bzip2"
  #COMPRESSION="lzma"
  #COMPRESSION="xz"
  #COMPRESSION="lzop"
  #COMPRESSION="lz4"

  # COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
  # Additional options for the compressor
  #COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=""
  ```
- It should load dropbear, should appear on 192.168.0.10 and allow me to decrypt the root disk

**What it does**

First, it apparently loads kernel and initrd (right?)
[image: First, it apparently loads kernel and initrd (right?)]

... then it does nothing any more
[image: ... then it does nothing any more]

... and it does not appear on the network. The LAN device lightens up though, it a cable is applied, but I cannot see anything to the IP (192.168.0.10) or the MAC of the device on the network.

**Question**

At what stage does it fail?

Does the kernel load successfully?

Does the initrd load successfully?

Does the network configuration fail?

Does dropbear fail?

Is there a structured way how to approach identifying the problem here?

**Note**

I was thinking that I probably need to include a few encryption modules in the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` (something like `MODULES="dm_crypt dm_mod ext4 aes"`). But this cannot possibly be the reason for the present problem, can it?

**Update (May 16th 2017)**

- including keyword `earlyprintk` in the `setenv` line in the `/boot/boot.txt` above (just after `bootargs`) will produce a lot more output in the early boot process.
- the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` must include hook `netconf` (before `dropbear`); otherwise it fails to configure the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding the questions**

- kernel and initrd were loading successfully
- the boot process failed to configure the network and did therefore prompt for the LUKS password in the local tty
- dropbear should work fine once the network configuration is successful

**Diagnosing the problem**

- including keyword `earlyprintk` in the `setenv` line in the `/boot/boot.txt` above (just after `bootargs`) will produce a lot more output in the early boot process.
- in the present case, this offered a bit more insight on the matter what was actually missing (both network configuration and modules for running the network device)
- in the absence of a clear idea what is wrong or how to solve it, the process involves a lot of trial and error (always removing the flash disk from the Raspberry Pi and mounting it in a laptop).

**Problem**

Both network configuration and modules for running the network device were missing.

**Solution**

I included a number of modules and more than one additional hook. I am not absolutely sure they are all necessary.

- the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` must include hook `netconf` (maybe also `net`) (before `dropbear`); otherwise it fails to configure the network.
- the driver for the network device (in my case `smsc95xx`) must be included as module.
- the network device is (internally) a usb device; therefore we also need usb drivers (also as modules: `g_cdc usb_f_acm usb_f_ecm` (maybe also `g_ether`)).

Alltogether `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` would look like so (uncommented lines only):

```
MODULES="<any encryption and filesystem modules you may need> g_cdc usb_f_acm usb_f_ecm smsc95xx g_ether"
BINARIES=""
FILES=""
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard net netconf dropbear encryptssh filesystems fsck"
```

Comment: The `net` hook is not required before the `netconf` hook which can be seen when comparing `/usr/lib/initcpio/{install,hooks}/net` to `/usr/lib/initcpio/{install,hooks}/netconf`: They both add `ipconfig` to the initial ramdisk and call this during boot to configure a network device.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.